# Последовательность функций

Tags: javascript

Как сделать последовательность выполнения функций без таймаута?

Comment: эээ... вызвать их подряд, без таймаута?

Answer (score 4):

Как сказал [@VladD](/users/10105/vladd), или к примеру так:

```
function func1(){
    document.write(1);
};
function func2(){
    document.write(2);
};
function func3(){
    document.write(3);
};
function QueueRun(queue){
    for (var i=0; i<queue.length; i++){
        queue[i]();
    };
};

var queue= new Array(func1, func2, func3);
QueueRun(queue);
```

Результат на [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ReinRaus/PUmBm/).

Comment: как-то всё сложно:

    [func1, func2, func3].forEach(function(func){
        func()
    })

Comment: Другой вид цикла и запись стала короче, но не проще.  
Да и писать эту конструкцию везде, где нужно запустить очередь не красиво.

Comment: создавать массив с помощью конструктора Array тоже не красиво, а простой и лаконичный

    [func1, func2, func3].forEach(run/*invoke*/)

вполне себе ничего

Comment: Дело вкуса   

    queue=[func1];
    queue.push(func2);
    queue2=[func2, func3];
    
    queue.forEach(function(func){
        func()
    });
    queue2.forEach(function(func){
        func()
    });
    
    QueueRun(queue);
    QueueRun(queue2);